# S3 = <(1 2), (2,3)>

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Dummit and Foote (p. 93) give the following example of the proposition that for H and K finite subgroups,

$|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$.

I quote literally: 
'If G = S3, H = <(1 2)> and K = <(2 3)>, then |H| = |K| = 2 and |H $\cap$ K| = 1, so |HK| = 4. By Lagrange's Theorem HK cannot be a subgroup. As a consequence, we must have S3 = <(1 2), (2 3)>.'

Although it is easy to follow the reasoning up to the last sentence, and to verify the last statement, I fail to see why S3 = <(1 2), (2 3)> is a consequence of HK not being a subgroup. Thank you for enlightening me on that.

Comment: $|\langle (1,2),(2,3) \rangle| \ge 4$ and divides $6$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @DerekHolt Do I understand well that the key ideas are that <H, K> is a subgroup and that |<H, K>| ≥ |HK|? Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely - indeed!